# Returning multiple values in PHP checking if they exist and are set

Tags: php

I have a value at `$field`

`$field` is a 5 digit number, and I have a folder full of images in image sets. So for each number e.g. "12345", there could be "12345_1" or "12345_2" etc. if multiple images exist.

I am using the following to check if each file exists, and then build a comma separated value for the files that do exist to insert into a CSV file.

For example, if A exists, and B exists, return "A,B"

I know what I am trying to achieve, and have the following...

```
if (file_exists('images/' . $field . '.JPG')) {
  $file1 = 'images/' . $field . '.JPG';
}

if (file_exists('images/' . $field . '_1.JPG')) {
  $file2 = 'images/' . $field . '_1.JPG';
}

if (file_exists('images/' . $field . '_2.JPG')) {
  $file3 = 'images/' . $field . '_2.JPG';
}

if((isset($file1)) && (!isset($file2)) && (!isset($file3))) {
  return "$file1";
} elseif((isset($file1)) && (isset($file2)) && (!isset($file3))) {
  return "$file1,$file2";
} elseif((isset($file1)) && (isset($file2)) && (isset($file3))) {
  return "$file1,$file2,$file3";
}
```

But this just seems like a really crap way of writing what I am trying to do, especially as in the real example, I am doing this for up to 10 files, so this is quite bulky.

Is there a better way to do this, or a method I am missing out on that could make life easier? (I'm still learning!)

Comment: Using an array and a loop would do a lot here. And you can already build your string using an `if` inside the first `if` statement.

Comment: Im struggling to figure out how to do a foreach if there is a number appended to each. There is also a max of ten files per image name, so I wouldn't want to crate an infinite check of whether 300 files exist etc.

Comment: You can use a simple `for` loop, then you already have your numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Old code probably didn't work as expected. Prepended `./` to `images` to find the right files. Now also using character ranges for case-insensitive file-extension search.

Why not [glob](http://php.net/glob)? It looks for files based on a pattern you pass it and return an array with matched files.

```
$files = glob ('./images/' . $field . '*.[jJ][pP][gG]');

if (is_array($files) && count($files)) {
   // if you need to remove the `./` from the front of the file name,
   // use the following line
   $files = array_map(function($val) { return substr($val, 2); }, $files);
   return implode(',', $files);
}
```

It can search directories using a wildcard. See the first  comment on  documentation page for an explanation of how it works. Basically, `*` is a wildcard meaning match any character.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
First in here you create a list of possible file endings (here up from _0.jpg`up to`_100.jpg`). The first one is the original without`_X.jpg`.

Then you loop over all and collect the existing files and finally implode them to get a comma sperated list.

```
$extensions = [".jpg",];
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){
    $extensions[] = sprintf("_%d.jpg", $i);
}
$existing_files = [];
foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $filename = "images/" . $file . $extension;
    if(file_exists($filename)){
        $existing_files[] = $filename;
    }
}

$result = implode(",", $existing_files);
```

Comment: Of course not! Thanks for pointing out, I was writing to fast :)

Answer (score 0):

It can all be done quite simply with a couple  of loops like this

```
$field = '123456';

$max_loop = 10;
$files_to_check = [];
$result = '';

// generate filenames with _number added
// first the odd filename with no additional numeric
$files_to_check[] = "images/$field.jpg";
// loop all the others
for ( $x=1; $x <= max_loop; $x++) {
    $files_to_check[] = sprintf('images/%s_%d.jpg', $field, $x); 
}

foreach ( $files_to_check as $file ) {
    if (file_exists($file) ) {
        $result = $file . ',';
    }
}
$result = trim($result, ',');

return $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I get a NOTICE Undefined variable: field_ on line number 13 with this. Can you put an underscore after a variable?

Comment: Ok, try that amendment using a sprintf instead of simple concatenation

Answer (score 0):

SPL (StandardPHPLibrary) can also do the job. I read the directory first, then check for it's existence by `isFile()` method  (also if it's a file) and finally store the matching filename to array.

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    $isFile = $fileinfo->isFile();
    $isMatch = stripos($fileinfo->getFilename(), $field) !== false;
    if ($isFile && $isMatch) {
        $myFile[] = $fileinfo->getFilename()
    }
}

echo implode(",", $myFile);
```

Read more: [`DirectoryIterator` PHP manual page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not calling function ,return is no need ! Assign one variable is better

```
$format = array(".JPG","_1.JPG","_2.JPG");
$file = array();
foreach ($format as $value) {
  if (file_exists('images/' . $field.$value)) {
  $file[] = 'images/'. $field.$value;
  }
}

$result = "";
$last = count($file)-1; //last index key
foreach ($file as $k=>$f) {
  if(isset($f)){
    ($last == $k) ? $result.= $f : $result.= $f.",";
  }
}
var_dump($result);
```